# Counting Pages per Sheet / Finding Automatic Page Breaks - Office JS - Excel

Tags: javascript, excel, office-js, office-addins

I'm building an Excel add-in using Office JS which, as part of its functionality, needs to do either (or both!) of the following:

1) I'm trying to figure out where the *automatic* page breaks currently are in a given sheet.

Excel has a nice way of finding page breaks given specific margins, page set up, etc., but sometimes I'd like to make minor adjustments in the case of spreadsheet [widows and orphans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Widows_and_orphans). Manual page breaks also don't solve my problem, since any auto-paginator I try to implement would have to rely on Excel's on-screen measurement system, which [isn't all that reliable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/determine-column-widths). I know those page breaks are being stored somewhere! I'm just looking for any way to read them.

2) The secondary, and probably easier goal, is to just figure out how many pages a spreadsheet is taking up, i.e. how *many* automatic page breaks are there. The Excel API doesn't seem to define any specific properties corresponding to this value, but the functionality existed at some point, since in VBA one can call ExecuteExcel4Macro("GET.DOCUMENT(50)") to get that value.

Any advice, timeline, or workarounds would be appreciated for either of these!

Comment: `I know those page breaks are being stored somewhere!` Yes they are. Here is how to check those values. **1.** Rename the `.xlsx` file to `.zip`. **2.** Open the zip file and go to `xl\worksheets` folder. **3.** Open the relevant sheet.xml. For ex: Sheet1.xml. **4.** The values will be stored in the relevant `<rowBreaks>` & `<colBreaks>` tags. 

BTW you may want to explore `VPageBreaks` & `HPageBreaks` in VBA. For Ex. `ws.VPageBreaks.Count` or `ws.VPageBreaks(1).Location.Address`. For page count you can use `Debug.Print ws.PageSetup.Pages.Count` Where `ws` is the respective sheet object.

Comment: This is an excellent start! Thank you very much Siddarth. The context for my question (which I didn't initially make clear) in an Excel add-in I'm building using Office JS, not VBA, and I've edited my question to make that more clear. I'll have to do some digging to see if I can access the raw XML of the workbook from the Excel API in Office JS as a workaround.

Comment: `The context for my question (which I didn't initially make clear) in an Excel add-in I'm building using Office JS, not VBA` Since VBA has nothing to do with this, I removed the VBA tag.